# Cannot Transfer VS 2015 Enterprise Xamarin License to Xamarin Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have an "VS 2015 Enterprise with Update 2" license.Logging to my Xamarin account with "VS 2015 with Update 2" gives this status to me:

[Visual Studio License on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHAnl.png)

However, as you seen, the “Enterprise” license don’t transferred to Xamarin Studio (latest version) on my Mac. How can I fix this issue ? Thanks.

[Xamarin Studio License Status on OS X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYLZk.jpg)

Comment: Contact Xamarin support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try to [manually resynchronize Xamarin licenses](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1641743-manually-refresh-xamarin-licenses) or [contact support by email](https://www.xamarin.com/support).